# Altering object is affecting previous versions of object in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, reference, foreach

So, this one is pretty straight forward I think.

Here is my code:

```
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> fileTypeListDict = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>();

foreach (PresentationFile pf in speakerAssignment.FKPresentation.PresentationFiles)
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> fileTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PresentationFileType))
                .Cast<PresentationFileType>().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
             Text = x.ToString(),
             Value = Convert.ToString((int)x),
             Selected = pf.Type == (int)x
        });

        fileTypeListDict.Add(pf.ID, fileTypes);
}
```

What is happening is that in the end the dictionary will have all the correct keys, but all of the values will be set to the `fileTypes` list created during the final iteration of the loop. I am sure this has something to do with the object being used as a reference, but have not seen this issue before in my time with C#. Anyone care to explain why this is happening and how I should resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the infamous "`foreach` capture issue", and is "fixed" in C# 5 ("fixed" is a strong word, since it suggests it was a "bug" before: in reality - the specification is now changed to acknowledge this as a common cause of confusion). In both cases, the lambda captures the **variable** `pf`, *not* "the value of `pf` during this iteration" - but in C# before-5 the variable `pf` is *technically* scoped *outside* the loop (so there is only one of them, period), where-as in C# 5 and above the variable is scoped *inside* the loop (so there is a different variable, for capture purposes, per iteration).

In C# 4, just cheat:

```
foreach (PresentationFile tmp in speakerAssignment.FKPresentation.PresentationFiles)
{
    PresentationFile pf = tmp;
    //... as before
```

now `pf` is scoped inside the `foreach`, and it will work OK. Without that, there is only one `pf` - and since you've deferred execution until the end, the *value* of the single `pf` will be the last iteration.

An alternative fix would be: don't defer execution:

```
fileTypeListDict.Add(pf.ID, fileTypes.ToList()); // note the ToList
```

Now it is evaluated *while the `pf` is "current"*, so will have the results you expected.

Comment: I appreciate the quick and thorough explanation. Have a great day!